# Calling an existing API using Express passing json body

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I am new to NodeJs / Express. I am trying to create an API which will in turn call an existing API which basically creates the product with some modification. basically the API "products" i am calling uses POST method. Which Basically expects data to be passed in JSON format. But here I get the error from the target API saying that body is not passed.

```
let json = {"id": "", "name" : ""};

      app.get('/createProduct/:product_id', function (req, res) {
        let url = 'https://somewebsite/api/products'
        json.id = req.params.product_id;

        req.headers['token'] = getToken();
        req.headers['timestamp'] = getTimeStamp();
        req.body = json;

        req.pipe(request(url)).pipe(res);
      });
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: what is <product json> ?

Comment: @JuhilSomaiya It's the Json I am supposed to pass to the target API as post request. Hence <product json> is nothing but the Json object containing Product details. Updating the question for better readability.

Comment: can you please try `app.use(function (req, res) {
request(url).pipe(res);
})`

Comment: You want to passing `token` and `timestamp` to headers and `req.body` to body before you call this `https://somewebsite/api/products`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to pipe the req object to the request call in this case, you could just make a request.post call, you can still pipe the output from this, I think it will give you the result you wish:

```
let json = {"id": "", "name" : ""};

app.get('/createProduct/:product_id', function (req, res) {
    let url = 'https://somewebsite/api/products';
    // Create headers for outgoing call.
    let headers = { 
        token: getToken(),
        timestamp: getTimeStamp()
    }
    // Populate the json.id value.
    json.id = req.params.product_id;
    request.post({ url, headers, body: json, json: true }).pipe(res);
});
```

Also for testing purposes, I suggest you create a POST listener to see what you're passing to the service, you can easily do this in express:

```
app.post("/post_test", bodyParser.json(), (req, res) => {
    console.info("/post_test: headers:", req.headers);
    console.info("/post_test: body:", req.body);
    res.status(201).send("All good");
})
```

To use this simply change the url in the app.get call to:

```
http://localhost:<port>/post_test
```

And remember to change back !

Comment: Thanks a ton!! I have been googling this for couple of days without any luck!!

Comment: No problemo! Glad to help!

Comment: what should i do if i don't want to display the result json but want to process and show output as html?

Comment: I would recommend looking at [res.render](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render), this allows you to generate html from an object. In this case you might not pipe the result from the API call, but rather save it to an object and pass this to the res.render call.